# Query to find the number of steps when looking for a destination

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql table:

```
id  origin  destination cost
1   SFO     JFK         500
2   SFO     DFW         200
3   SFO     MCO         400
4   DFW     MCO         100
5   DFW     JFK         200
6   JFK     LHR        1000
```

I want to lists the possible trips that can be done in two or fewer stops. I want to display the columns origin, destination, stops (number of stops of the trip), and total_cost.
So, for this particular case:

```
origin  destination stops   total_cost
DFW     JFK         0        200
DFW     LHR         1       1200
DFW     MCO         0        100
JFK     LHR         0       1000
SFO     DFW         0        200
SFO     JFK         1        400
SFO     LHR         2      1400
SFO     MCO         1        300
```

I think I need to do do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f1.origin,  f1.destination, f1.cost FROM flights f1
    INNER JOIN flights f2 ON (f1.destination = f2.origin OR f1.destination = f2.destination)
```

But, this is obviously not working, any hint?

Comment: the database engine is MySQL

Comment: Why is that obviously not working?

Comment: because the number of stops column isn't there, for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT f1.origin,  f1.destination, 0 as stops, f1.cost 
        FROM flights f1
    union
    SELECT DISTINCT f1.origin,  f2.destination, 1 as stops, f1.cost + f2.cost 
        FROM flights f1
        JOIN flights f2 ON f1.destination = f2.origin
```

Comment: and how do you calculate the number of stops?

Comment: it looks nice, the only thing is that 2 stops is also possible, so then I added this:

UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT f1.origin,  f3.destination, f1.cost + f2.cost + f3.cost , 2 as stops
        FROM flights f1
        JOIN flights f2 ON f2.origin = f1.destination 
        JOIN flights f3 ON f2.destination = f3.origin

But, I get duplicated entries, because you can go from one airport to another with 0 or 1 stop, for example, and I need to chose the lowest in cost

Comment: That is changing the question and requires a different post. You can't keep moving the target. Your question says:"I want to lists the possible trips that can be done in two or fewer stops. I want to display the columns origin, destination, stops (number of stops of the trip), and total_cost. " I have answered that question. If you like my answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `union all`.  This is rather tricky and CTEs will help:

```
with s1 as (
      select f1.origin, f2.destination, 1 as stops, f1.cost + f2.cost as cost
      from flights f1 join
           flights f2
           on f1.destination = f2.origin
      where (f1.origin, f2.destination) not in (select f.origin, f.destination from flights)
     ),
     s2 as (
      select f1.origin, f3.destination, 2 as stops, f1.cost + f2.cost + f3.cost as cost
      from flights f1 join
           flights f2
           on f1.destination = f2.origin join
           flights f3
           on f2.destination = f3.origin
      where (f1.origin, f2.destination) not in (select f.origin, f.destination from flights) and
            (f1.origin, f2.destination) not in (select f.origin, f.destination from s1)
     )
select f.origin, f.destination, 1 as stops, f.cost
from flights f
union all
select s1.origin, s1.destination, 1 as stops, s1.cost
from s1
union all
select s2.origin, s2.destination, 1 as stops, s2.cost
from s2;
```

Note:  This could return multiple rows for the same pair if there is more than one way to get from the origin to destination with a given number of hops.

Comment: I'm getting circular reference: s2